# Waring's problem over $\mathbb Q_{\ge0}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $k$ be a positive integer. Note that $a/b=ab^{k-1}/b^k$ for any integers $a$ and $b>0$.
If every $n\in\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ can be written as $x_1^k+\cdots+x_{s}^k$ with $x_1,\ldots,x_s\in\mathbb N$, then each $r\in\mathbb Q_{\ge0}$ can be written as $x_1^k+\cdots+x_s^k$ with $x_1,\ldots,x_s\in\mathbb Q_{\ge0}$, where
$$\mathbb Q_{\ge0}=\{r\in\mathbb Q:\ r\ge0\}.$$

Instead of the classical Waring problem over $\mathbb N$, we may consider Waring's problem over $\mathbb Q_{\ge0}$. Let $s(k)$ be the least positive integer $s$ such that each $r\in\mathbb Q_{\ge0}$ can be written as $x_1^k+\ldots+x_s^k$ with $x_1,\ldots,x_s\in\mathbb Q_{\ge0}$. Then
$s(k)$ exists and moreover $s(k)\le g(k)$. It is interesting to find the exact value of $s(k)$.

By Theorems 233 and 234 in Hardy and Wright's book *A Introduction to the Theory of Numbers*, we have $s(3)=3$ (the inequality $s(3)\le 3$ was obtained by Richmond in 1923).

**Question.** Can one prove that $s(k)\ge k$ for each integer $k>2$? Is it true that $s(4)=5$?

Your comments are welcoeme!

Comment: It is trivial that $g(k)\ge k$ for any positive integer $k$.

Comment: In fact we have $s(k)\leq G(k)$, where $G(k)$ is the least number of $k$-th powers whose sum represents every sufficiently large positive integer. This is because a positive rational number can be written as $a/b=ab^{k-1}/b^k$ with arbitrary large $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can answer the last question: $s(4)$ equals $15$, not $5$. Variables below will denote integers.

First we show that $s(4)\leq 15$. We use the result of [Davenport (1939)](http://djvu.org/) that there exists $m\geq 1$ such that every positive integer outside $\{16^h k:\text{$h\geq 0$ and $k\leq m$}\}$ is a sum of $15$ integral biquadrates. Now let $a,b\geq 1$ arbitrary, and let $n$ be an odd number such that $n^4>m$. Then $ab^3n^4$ is a sum of $15$ integral biquadrates, hence $a/b$ is a sum of $15$ rational biquadrates.

Now we show that $s(4)\geq 15$. It suffices to show that $15$ is not the sum of $14$ rational biquadrates. Equivalently, $15 n^4$ (for $n\geq 1$) is not the sum of $14$ integral biquadrates. Assume that $15n^4$ is the sum of $14$ integral biquadrates, with $n\geq 1$ minimal. We shall use twice that every integral biquadrate is $\equiv 0,1\pmod{16}$. If $n$ is even, then $15 n^4\equiv 0\pmod{16}$, so every biquadrate in the decomposition is even. That is, $15(n/2)^4$ is also the sum of $14$ integral biquadrates, contradicting the minimality of $n$. If $n$ is odd, then $15 n^4\equiv 15\pmod{16}$, while a sum of $14$ biquadrates is $\equiv 0,\dotsc,14\pmod{16}$. This is again a contradiction.

Comment: The same argument shows $s(2^k) \geq 2^{k+2}-1$ for all $k \geq 2$, I guess, but known results on Waring's problem for sufficiently large $n$ will not be close to that for larger $k$.

Comment: @WillSawin: Good observation. I think it is safe to conjecture, keeping in mind the conjectures on $G(m)$, that $s(2^k)=2^{k+2}-1$. Lower bounds on $G(m)$ for general $m$ seem more elusive.

Comment: Probably this follows from standard conjectures (Brauer-Manin obstruction is the only obstruction to the Hasse principle for Fano varieties). These suggest that $s(m)$ is at most the max of $m$ and the minimum $s$ such that there is no local obstruction. Then one just has to check the $p$-adic obstructions stop before the 2-adic ones.